# Convert all the number values to string in JSON using Java

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I need to convert all the number values to string in my JSON file to overcome a `NumberFormatException` due to exceeding the `Long.Max_Value` limit. I am using json-simple `JSONParser` and it throws an exception. What's the best way to convert them in Java?
At the moment, I can't even parse the file completely due this exception.

Comment: Ideally you'd want to use BigDecimal or BigInteger in those cases. Looks like there's a patch for that, but it's not in master yet: https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/issues/73

Answer (score 0):

look this examples https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide . Google gson library is probably what you need:

1. can convert object to json
2. can convert json to object

and many other functions